# Linux task state different in /proc/pid/stat compared to Ftrace output of sched events

Tags: linux, proc, scheduling, multithreading, ftrace

I'm trying to trace the flow of a piece of code just to understand the points where the tasks go into D/S/R states (uninterruptible/interruptible/running). I do understand the meaning of each state, however doing an exercise shows confusing results and I wasn't able till now to figure out why.

The piece of code I'm running:

```
void foo() {

    pthread_setname_np(pthread_self(), "lock_func/1");

    while(quit == false)
    {
        for(int64_t idx=0; idx<10000000;idx++)
            (void)idx;
        flag = true;
        cv1.notify_all();
    }
}

void bar() {

    pthread_setname_np(pthread_self(), "lock_func/2");
    std::mutex mutex1;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex1);
    while(!flag)
        cv1.wait(lock);
    flag = false;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    ...
    std::thread t1 = std::thread(foo);
    std::thread t2 = std::thread(bar);
    ...
    if (mlockall( MCL_CURRENT | MCL_FUTURE ) < 0) { 
        perror("mlockall") 
    }
    ....   
}
```

I purposely don't use the mutex when setting the flag as I don't want the foo thread to block. So I don't care if bar misses some wakeups, it will be anyway woken up from time to time due to the loop in **foo**. The goal here is just to see the states of **foo & bar** task, now more focusing on **bar**.
If I trace the sched_switch event in the ftrace, I do get the following:

```
      <idle>-0     [007] d...       335998: sched_switch: prev_comm=swapper/7 prev_pid=0 prev_prio=120 prev_state=S ==> next_comm=lock_func/1 next_pid=30296 next_prio=120
 lock_func/1-30296 [007] d...       335999: sched_switch: prev_comm=lock_func/1 prev_pid=30296 prev_prio=120 prev_state=D ==> next_comm=swapper/7 next_pid=0 next_prio=120
      <idle>-0     [007] d...       336000: sched_switch: prev_comm=swapper/7 prev_pid=0 prev_prio=120 prev_state=S ==> next_comm=lock_func/1 next_pid=30296 next_prio=120
 lock_func/1-30296 [007] d...       336001: sched_switch: prev_comm=lock_func/1 prev_pid=30296 prev_prio=120 prev_state=D ==> next_comm=swapper/7 next_pid=0 next_prio=120
      <idle>-0     [007] d...       336002: sched_switch: prev_comm=swapper/7 prev_pid=0 prev_prio=120 prev_state=S ==> next_comm=lock_func/1 next_pid=30296 next_prio=120
 lock_func/1-30296 [007] d...       336003: sched_switch: prev_comm=lock_func/1 prev_pid=30296 prev_prio=120 prev_state=D ==> next_comm=swapper/7 next_pid=0 next_prio=120
      <idle>-0     [007] d...       336004: sched_switch: prev_comm=swapper/7 prev_pid=0 prev_prio=120 prev_state=S ==> next_comm=lock_func/1 next_pid=30296 next_prio=120
 lock_func/1-30296 [007] d...       336005: sched_switch: prev_comm=lock_func/1 prev_pid=30296 prev_prio=120 prev_state=D ==> next_comm=swapper/7 next_pid=0 next_prio=120
      <idle>-0     [007] d...       336006: sched_switch: prev_comm=swapper/7 prev_pid=0 prev_prio=120 prev_state=S ==> next_comm=lock_func/1 next_pid=30296 next_prio=120
 lock_func/1-30296 [007] d...       336007: sched_switch: prev_comm=lock_func/1 prev_pid=30296 prev_prio=120 prev_state=D ==> next_comm=swapper/7 next_pid=0 next_prio=120
      <idle>-0     [007] d...       336008: sched_switch: prev_comm=swapper/7 prev_pid=0 prev_prio=120 prev_state=S ==> next_comm=lock_func/1 next_pid=30296 next_prio=120
 lock_func/1-30296 [007] d...       336009: sched_switch: prev_comm=lock_func/1 prev_pid=30296 prev_prio=120 prev_state=D ==> next_comm=swapper/7 next_pid=0 next_prio=120
      <idle>-0     [000] d...       336010: sched_switch: prev_comm=swapper/0 prev_pid=0 prev_prio=120 prev_state=S ==> next_comm=lock_func/1 next_pid=30296 next_prio=120
 lock_func/1-30296 [000] d...       336011: sched_switch: prev_comm=lock_func/1 prev_pid=30296 prev_prio=120 prev_state=D ==> next_comm=swapper/0 next_pid=0 next_prio=120
      <idle>-0     [000] d...       336012: sched_switch: prev_comm=swapper/0 prev_pid=0 prev_prio=120 prev_state=S ==> next_comm=lock_func/1 next_pid=30296 next_prio=120
```

Observe how prev_state for my lock_func1 (bar) is always **D** (uninterruptible). Looking at the code a context switch can happen only on the condition variable sleep, or when time slice is finished (running in CFS scheduler)

```
cat /proc/30295/task/30296/wchan
futex_wait_queue_me
```

which according to the docs is a interruptible function.
Checking multiple times the task state in proc shows always **S**:

```
cat /proc/30295/task/30296/stat
30295 (lock_func/1) S ...
```

So the stat shows S-interruptible state, the **futex_wait_queue_me** is interruptible, however, the ftrace show always at the context switch time **prev_state=D**. Running this code and recording several seconds with ftrace shows only **prev_state=D** for my lock_func/1 (bar). I never get the S-interruptible.

Can someone explain why? Is the scheduler doing some state change in between?

Thanks.